# How to recover a Fedora Server 36 storage pool after upgrading to v37?

Tags: server, storage, fedora

I recently upgraded Fedora Server (F) v36 to v37. The F36 server had a volume group consisting of three physical drives combined to form a storage pool, which I named “BigDrive”. During the upgrade the logical volume information seems to have been lost and BigDrive didn’t appear or mount in the F37 server. I’ve been unable to find any backup logical volume information. At present the 3 drives are installed on the F37 server. I would welcome advise on how to recombine the three drives, recover the logical volume information, and access the data stored in the shared pool. Can anyone suggest a process to do that, or a utility that could rebuild the storage pool from the physical drives?

I haven't found any helpful information in the various Fedora documentation or usual websites that don't reference using the backed up logical volume information which somehow didn't survive the upgrade process. This is because the OS hard drive was wiped and repartitioned as part of the upgrade. The drives that formed the storage pool were not formatted, nor do they store any OS or application files. They were purely data storage.

Comment: Does `pvscan` show anything?

Comment: BigDrive does not show up in a pvscan

Comment: I believe I need a recovery tool that will recombine the physical disks into a logical volume and then reconstruct the system file table for the logical volume.

Comment: Your _"storage pool"_ is `lvm`, yes?  It should be possible to just take a physical `lvm` and plug it into a new system and then use it (after some configuration).

Comment: I've tried that and it just shows up as an unformatted pool.

Comment: what is the output of `pvs`, `vgs`, and `lvs`?